# Laravel 5 from Pivot-Table to Many

Tags: laravel

how can I access in Laravel 5 from the pivot table the users if i have a relation like this:

```
users (id)
roles (id)
user_role (user_id, role_id)
```

I select the user_id's and now i want the users.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your relations in User model and Role model. Please refer to the laravel documantation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: OK so where are you stuck ?

Comment: How can i select the users? userRole(alle_user_ids)->users() something like this.

Comment: If you've done the relationships correctly, you will be able to access users like this: $role = Role::find(1); $role->users();